# How to send data from a webservice to a specific android application?

Tags: php, android, web-services

I have wrote my own webservice in PHP that is supposed to generate OTPs, I send them through email without any problem, the main issue is that I want these OTPs to be send into a specific android application (I do not want other android applications be able to read it).

Comment: Web-services don't usually "send" data to applications without getting a request from applications first. I think we're missing a chunk of the problem description here.

Comment: well yes I know that, assume that any programmer can wrote an android application and send a request to my web-service, how can I prevent that?

Comment: One way is to ask for authentication, of whatever kind it is...

Comment: You can implement ssh connection, so just get the public key of your android and authorize it on the server for public key authentication

Comment: You can use [Public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography). The idea is you generate a public private key pair for each application you allow access to your web-services and they use those to sign requests which you can then verify and determine if they're authentic (i.e. they're generated using keys you gave them).

Answer (score 0):

If you're the owner/provider of the recipient app you could send them using GCM's Push notifications (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) downstream messages (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream)

Put your OTP data, in the 'data' part of the payload.

Of course all of this implies that you register all your client devices token at the server level, hence the need to have access to both the server and device app code